# How can I call python code from a FORTRAN Code?

Tags: python, fortran, abaqus

I have written a python code for modeling a structure in Abaqus. I have checked it by `abaqus cae noGUI=mycode.py` in command window (That's how Abaqus is called to run that code). It works completely. I also have written a `UMAT` code in abaqus (in Fortran). I need to call the Python code in that `UMAT` code.

I used `st=system('abaqus cae noGUI=mycode.py')` and `st` is a integer. However, the python code is not called. I created a batch file in which I wrote `abaqus cae noGUI=mycode.py`. I called that file in UMAT by `st=system('code.bat')` and I got the error that `code.bat` is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the introductory [tour] and read [ask]. We need to see your code.

Comment: Yes, more details are welcome since it looks a priori like you are going against the philosophy of the use of FORTRAN, Abaqus, and Python...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. To elaborate it more, I need to create a batch file which do the same task as abaqus cae noGUI=mycode.py in the command window. I simply write this line in a file and saved that as .bat file format. However, it is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile Python scripts for use in FORTRAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805244/how-to-compile-python-scripts-for-use-in-fortran)

Answer (score 1):

Running an Abaqus/CAE Python script, or even calling the built-in Python interpreter, from a Fortran subroutine can certainly be done. I've found it to be very useful in certain edge-cases, with caveats. *Use with caution*.

You seem to be on the right track, however you must remember to **use the full file path** for all external files specified in an Abaqus subroutine. 
You'll find the Abaqus utility subroutines `getjobname` and `getoutdir` useful. Here's a barebones example snippet, with a few variable definitions tossed in:

```
use ifport, only: system, ierrno    !! Note: `USE` must come before any `INLCUDE`

character(len=256)                  :: outdir, jobname
character(len=:), allocatable       :: cwd, cmd
integer                             :: jobnamelen, outdirlen, rc, errnum

call getjobname(jobname, jobnamelen)
call getoutdir(outdir, outdirlen)
cwd = outdir(1:outdirlen)
cmd = 'abaqus cae nogui=' // cwd // '/my_script.py' 

rc = system(cmd)
if (rc .eq. -1) then
  errnum = ierrno( )
  print *, 'Error: ', errnum
endif
```

---

<sub>Notes:</sub>

<sub>1. If the full path is not specified, Abaqus will assume that external files exist/will be created in the scratch directory. This is not typically the same as the current work directory.</sub>

<sub>2. Code snippet shown above was tested with success using `uexternaldb` and a generic "hello world"-style Python script.</sub>

<sub>3. If you are using ifort 17 or later (and if you care), you should also be able to replace the `ifport` portability functions with the Fortran 2008 intrinsic `execute_command_line`.</sub>

<sub>4. You can use a batch file, however, the batch file (as well as the Python script mentioned within the batch file) must still have the full file path.</sub>