# Multiplying two 2D numpy arrays to a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've got two 2D `numpy` arrays called `A` and `B`, where `A` is `M x N` and `B` is `M x n`. My problem is that I wish to multiply **each element of each row** of `B` with corresponding **row** of `A` and create a 3D matrix `C` which is of size `M x n x N`, without using `for`-loops.

As an example, if `A` is:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6]])
```

and `B` is

```
B = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]])
```

Then the resulting multiplication `C = A x B` would look something like

```
C = [
     [[1, 2],
      [12, 16]],
     [[2, 4],
      [15, 20]],
     [[3, 6],
      [18, 24]]
     ]
```

Is it clear what I'm trying to achieve, and is it possible doing without any `for`-loops? Best, tingis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the NumPy Einstein summation function, [einsum()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
C=np.einsum('ij,ik->jik',A,B)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This funcition helps a lot, will go with your solution!

Comment: `einsum` can do wondrous things, i think it is also faster than other numpy vector product methods. Also, by changing the index order after ->, you can do a reshape without an extra call to the actual `reshape`.

Comment: @yevgeniy about being faster, [It depends on the size of the array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30645430/832621). Usually it is faster for smaller arrays, while for larger arrays I measured speeds comparable to the method using `newaxis`

Comment: @SaulloCastro. Thanks for running an actual test. I was also following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083997/huge-speed-difference-in-numpy-between-similar-code), where `einsum` really showed great performance, so it seems at array size >10000 is where one should consider alternative solutions.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible by creating a new axis in each array and transposing the modified `A`:

```
A[np.newaxis,...].T * B[np.newaxis,...]
```

giving:

```
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [12, 16]],

       [[ 2,  4],
        [15, 20]],

       [[ 3,  6],
        [18, 24]]])
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer! Going with yev's answer though, as he needs the points ;D