# How to compile and package a python file into an execution file under windows 64bit

Tags: python, package, exe, theano, py2exe

Recently, I started to use theano to do some basic BP network. The theano was installed and my network based on theano works well in my PC. 
In order to share my code among my colleagues, I am looking for a method to package the theano python file to one execution file which can be run under windows without python environment.

I am trying py2exe to finish the packaging work and I found that, the packaged exe can only work in my PC. When I copy the exe to other PCs without python, it does not work. Only warning message is giving as:

```
“WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! 

Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.”
```

My **working environment** is:
**Win10 64bit + Anaconda2**

Could anyone give me some advice to generate the exe file based on theano python file?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a python program be run on a computer without Python? What about C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894048/can-a-python-program-be-run-on-a-computer-without-python-what-about-c-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

PyInstaller is a program that freezes (packages) Python programs into stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX.

Answer (score 0):

I use `cxFreeze` to convert my Python scripts to `.exe` Its a really good module. You can see its working [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HosXxXE24hA).