# Python script slower as .exe than as .py

Tags: python, performance, pyside, py2exe, modbus

I'm writing an app in Python that uses among others *PySide* for the GUI and also [*modbus_tk*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/modbus_tk) for Modbus communications between my PC and an embedded controller.

I've noticed that **when I byte-compile my script to a Windows application** (.exe), using *py2exe*, **the requests are sent to the controller slower** than with the Python script (.py).

Have you ever experienced something like this ? Is it normal ? What should I do to speed up my program ? Any help would be highly valued.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Py2exe

> Although this program transforms a .py file to an .exe, it does not make it run faster as py2exe just bundles the Python bytecode rather than converting it to machine-code. It may even run slower than using the Python interpreter directly because of startup overhead.

You can't compile (standard) Python code.

Comment: So it comes from _py2exe_... Do you suggest I try another converter (like _cx_Freeze_) or is it a lost cause ? I'll try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138521/is-it-feasible-to-compile-python-to-machine-code) in the meantime

Comment: There is plenty ways to speed up Python code (multiprocessing, lazy programing, ...) but compiling is not. If you really want to go ultra-fast, you could consider recoding the heavy (in algorithmic sense) part of your code in a compiled language and call it from Python (with Popen for example)

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! I think my Python code is pretty efficient though, what takes time is the Modbus communication (takes longer with the .exe than with the .py). Perhaps I should convert the library I'm using to C/C++...